# Prove the function $f(x) = (a*x)^{-1}$ is bijective

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

There is a Group $(G,*,I)$, let $a \in G$. Define $f:G \rightarrow G$ by $f(x) = (a*x)^{-1}$ for all $x \in G$. Prove that $f$ is bijective.

So it means that we need to prove injectivity and surjectivity both.

I have tried proving the subjectivity for it as follows:

choose $x=a^{-1}*y^{-1}$

so $f(x) = (a*x)^{-1} $

$= (a*(a^{-1}*y^{-1}))^{-1}    $

$= (a^{-1}*y^{-1})^{-1}*a^{-1}$  $\qquad${ def:  $(a*b)^{-1} = a^{-1}*b^{-1}$ }

$= y*a*a^{-1}$ $\qquad \qquad \qquad${ def:  $(a*b)^{-1} = a^{-1}*b^{-1}$ }

$= y$

*I am not able to prove the injectivity. Can anyone help me in this regard?*

*Also just let me know if my proof for surjectivity is correct?*

Comment: I am still not able to prove the injectivity for it ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve:
$$
(a*x)^{-1} = (a*y)^{-1}
$$
to find that the only possiblity is $x=y$. To solve the equation you take inverse of both sides then multiply by inverse of $a$ both sides.

Your proof of suriectivity seems correct to me.

Anyway bijectivity of this function is apparent if you notice that $f$ is the composition of two functions: $x\mapsto a*x$ and $x\mapsto x^{-1}$. It is good to know that both these functions are bijective.

Comment: you mean I should equate both $f(x)=f(y)$ 

then $(a*x)^{-1}=(a*y)^{-1}$

$x^{-1}*a^{-1} = y^{-1}*a^{-1}  \qquad $  by def { $(a*b)^{-1} = a^{-1}*b^{-1}$ }  but then I am stuck here and cannot come to conclusion of $x=y$

Comment: The inverse of $(a*x)^{-1}$ is $a*x$.

Comment: I tried taking the Inverse both sides i.e . $(a*x)^{-1} = (a*y)^{-1}$, $(a*x)^{-1} *  (a*x) = (a*y)^{-1} * (a*y)$ but this then leads to $I=I$. I am not able to apply the feedback provided by you.

Comment: Taking the inverse of both sides you get: $a*x = a*y$... This is elementary algebra, like when you want to simplify the equation $1/(7x) = 1/(7y)$.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thank you so much for your feedback.